# MEF import properties null in class activated at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I have a factory which returns a class instance (Object Factory)

```
var object = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IObjectBase; 
return object;
```

Then in my `IObjectBase`, all of my import values are null when I try to do something inside my controller

```
[Import] public IObjectFactory ObjectFactory {get; set;}

var getNewObject = ObjectFactory.GetObject(); 
getNewObject.DoSomething();
```

Here is where the problem is, all the import services here are null

```
[Export(typeof(IObjectBase))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class ObjectBase : IObjectBase
{
    [Import] public IService SomeService {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this one interesting since the Activator.CreateInstance creates an instance of the class on runtime (correct me if I'm wrong) hence, MEF cannot already construct the imports here.

Instead of Activator.CreateInstance, I used ServiceLocator.GetInstance(IObjectBase)